# Can I set entry point at code in PE headers?

Tags: x86, pe, windows-8

If I set something like `0x00000040` (my code is located at this address), then the program crashes with this error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
```

But if I `jmp` from the code section to 0x00400040 then it works.

Why did I get error with that strange address (`0xc000007b`) ? Is it possible to start the execution of program from code which is located outside sections?

I use Windows 8.

Comment: If you set 0x00000040 where?

Comment: 0x40 as Address of EP in optional header (0x110 offset)

Comment: The error is defined in `ntstatus.h` of the WDK. The error code has existed for a long time and is known under its symbolic name as `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 12):

Windows 8 introduces a new restriction: the `AddressOfEntryPoint` can't be smaller than `SizeOfHeaders`.

Set `SizeOfHeaders` to `AddressOfEntryPoint` to [make it work](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/diff?spec=svn1731&old=1729&r=1731&format=unidiff&path=/trunk/src/PE/mini.asm).

The error you get is defined in `ntstatus.h` as follows:

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT
//
// MessageText:
//
// {Bad Image}
// %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status 0x%08lx.
//
#define STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT      ((NTSTATUS)0xC000007BL)
```